# Chrome Bookmark Synchronisation Duplicating Bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have chrome set up to synchronise bookmarks.

I use chrome on two laptops.

I've been trying to re-organise my growing collection of bookmarks.

Synchronisation seems to be creating duplicates IF I move a bookmark from one folder to another, later on, after a synchronisation the bookmark reappears in the original location.

Any idea how I can stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi the issue is that chrome does an incremental sync and whatever you delete on one will be restored because it exists on the other.
I had the same issue because i had synced bookmarks on my home PC and work PC.
I came across this as the solution, what you basically need to do is:

1. remove both PCs from the sync,
2. delete the backup on the cloud,
3. organize bookmarks on one PC,
4. upload bookmarks to cloud through that PC (enable sync),
5. remove chrome user data from other PC,
6. add sync back on.

Below link will help as well:
[Delete duplicates from over 150,000 bookmarks on Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/746622/delete-duplicates-from-over-150-000-bookmarks-on-google-chrome)